# How to pass variables from one php to the next using JQuery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to simply just pass (or POST) a variable indicated by the user in a textbox to another .php for processing.

This is my POST function in javascript.

```
function POST() {

    var name = $('#name').val();

    $.post('pages/searchResult.php',{name:name}, function (data) {
        $('#name_feedback').html(data);
    });
}
```

This is how the user indicates the variable through a textbox and submit.

```
  <div id="name_feedback"></div>
  <div style="text-align: center"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter first or last name" name="name" id="name" class="textbox"/></div>                           
    <div style="text-align: center"><a href="main index.php?page=searchResult"><input type="Submit" value="Search" class="css_button" id="searchBtn" onclick="POST();"/></a></div>
```

I am not sure why but my .php wont receive the variable..

```
<?php

    //include('connect.php');

    $pointData = array();
    $dateData = array();

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $query = "SELECT * from `users` WHERE firstName = '$name' OR lastName = '$name' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query); //<<<
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $userid = $row['id'];
    echo mysql_error();

?>
```

I am using this video as a reference:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EHbBHm5l4g

Comment: Why do you have a button in an anchor?

Comment: Does the AJAX call happen (check with Chrome developer tools, F12)? What is the content of `$_POST` (use `var_dump`)?

Comment: Yeah it loads just fine through the onclick="POST()".

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 var name = $('#name').val();
 $.post('pages/searchResult.php',{"name":name}, function (data) {
    $('#name_feedback').html(data);
 }) .fail(function(err) {
       alert( "error" +err);
 });
```

At your php script side, you can `echo` the data which you want to return back based on success of the  query search.

remove the single around the table name `users` and around `$name` from the below

`"SELECT * from`users`WHERE firstName = '$name' OR lastName = '$name' LIMIT 1";`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: First of all, thank you for that. I am glad to see some positive attitudes xD. Unfortunately, the demn thing is still saying that my $name = $_POST['name']; is undefined.. :(

Comment: Just for the record, I don't need the return. I just want the variable to be passed :/

Comment: Syntax looks good, well you can do some diagnostic checks like 1. add a `fail` block to your ajax call .`.fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})`. 2. verify the target php script url in ajax call.